# Entity is deleted error when creating records on a custom object (many-to-many)

Tags: custom, delete

On a custom Role__c join object that I created to establish a many to many relationship Account and Contact I am not able to upsert or create records that have been deleted. It will throw this error for every record: `ENTITY IS DELETED`

I can do so with Account or Contact:

1. Add records
2. Delete them
3. Create them again

But the 3rd step fails if I try to do it for the custom object Role__c, with the message about records being deleted. Any idea of why this is happening? It happens using either the Bulk Api or the REST Api.

Comment: The issue was that when pulling the records from the parent tables (Account and Contact), I wasn't filtering out the records that are in the recycle bin, hence trying to link the juntion object to records that were deleted. (to filter use WHERE isDeleted = false) in your query.

Comment: Hey htache, please answer your own question with the contents of that comment. It is allowed and this could be of use to people in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that when pulling the records from the parent tables (Account and Contact), I wasn't filtering out the records that are in the recycle bin, hence trying to link the junction object to records that were deleted. (to filter use WHERE isDeleted = false) in your query.